# Refreshing the DB

Tags: database, vba, connection

my issue is that when i try to access at the database after a change (insert, update...) the query return the old data.

I explain further:

i have two datatables:
- the first one is filled with the current month datas as per below:

```
            tbastorico.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MC Capital\MC Capital\App_Data\MC Capital Ltd.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            tbastorico.InsertQuerydDaTabellone(riga.IDcliente, riga.Cognome, riga.SubAm, ......)
```

- after loading the data, when i call the select query on the first table returns 0 rows as the table was empty. But the data are in the mdf file.

Can you help me?

Comment: I've run into this before.  the insert statement isn't complete when the select statement is processed.  You may think that because the insert is first in code and that it returns that the select would return what was inserted because it's not done.  IF you insert 150 records or so into the database, and monitor the insert and your code, you'll see that around 80 get "Done" before the select fires.  Wrapping the insert code in a transaction logic MAY help.  We ended up looping the select statement and checking record count as we knew how many to expect.

Comment: The two queries are in two different button and i call the select after the insert is done

Comment: Still sounds similar to me we had different buttons.  perchance are the Select and insert statements looking at two Different access databases? (yet modeled similar?)

Comment: they are looking to same table, in the same db

Comment: I guess I'd need to see the table structure and select at this point.  Unless you're limiting results though improper joins or where clause criteria, I can't imagine why it would do this.  (Does the same query when setup in Access Return results?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I built the db as a services based db into Visual Studio, i manage the db with the tableadapters. Below the two queries:

Comment: INSERT INTO Storico
                         (IDcliente, Cognome, ...)
VALUES        (@idcliente,@cognome, ...)
       then i call the select query with the tba:
                          Dim promsub As MC_Capital_LtdDataSet.StoricoDataTable = tbastor.GetDataOverByProm(riga.promID)
                         the query is:
                         SELECT        *
FROM            Storico
where idPFC=@id or idPFS=@id or idPFSA=@id

Comment: there are NO NULL values in the db

Comment: in addition there are NO join and NO PRIMARY KEY in the two tabs, one table is just the collection of the daily fees of each month, the second contains the assessment of the amount due based on the first table. The structure is very easy, i just pick up the data from the csv, add the datas to the first table, evaluate the monthly amount and storing them in the second table